# Hessian of non differentiable convex function

Tags: reference-request, approximation-algorithms, convex-optimization

The motivation of the question is the following:

Let $P$ be a set of $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Consider the following objective(convex and differentiable) function $f:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow [0,\infty)$.

> $f(c) = \sum_{p\in P}\Vert p-c\Vert^2$.

It is well known that the mean $\mu(P)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{p\in P}p$ minimizes the function over $\mathbb{R}^d$. More generally, for any $c\in \mathbb{R}^d$ the following is true

> $f(c) = f(\mu(P)) + n\Vert c-\mu(P)\Vert^2$.

There are various ways to prove this. For example we can compute the gradient

> $\nabla f(c) = \sum_{p\in P}2(c-p)$

Since $f$ is convex, for $c^\star = \mu(P)$, we have $\nabla f(c^\star) = 0$. The Hessian is $\nabla^2 f(c)=2nI$, $I$ being the Identity matrix. Now consider the second order approximation

> $f(c) = f(c^\star) + \langle \nabla f(c^\star), c-c^\star\rangle + \frac{1}{2}(c-c^\star)^T\nabla^2f(\theta)(c-c^\star) = f(c^\star) + n\Vert c-c^\star\Vert^2$, for some $\theta\in [c,c^\star]$.

**Coming to the main question**

Let $\mathcal{P} = \left\{P_1,\cdots,P_n \right\}$ be a family of $n$ finite sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Consider the following (convex) function

> $F(c) = \sum_{j\in[n]}\max_{p\in P_j}\Vert p-c\Vert^2$

Given $c\in\mathbb{R}^d$, let $p_j\in P_j$ such that $\Vert p_j-c\Vert^2=\max_{p\in P_j}\Vert p-c\Vert^2$. Then one can show that $G(c) = \sum_{j\in[n]}2(c-p_j)$ is a valid "sub gradient" of $F$ at $c$ ($\in \partial F(c)$). It is well known that $c^\star$ minimizes $F$ iff $0\in \partial F(c^\star)$. Therefore, $c^\star = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j\in[n]} p_j$ is **a** minimizer of $F$. Now I want find out how changing the point effects the function(similar to the above). For that one needs **an analogue of Hessian** for non differentiable functions, where the "sub gradient" exists.

So is there a way to compute something similar to the Hessian, when the function is non-differentiable?

PS. After Googling, I found the paper [GENERALIZED HESSIAN PROPERTIES
OF REGULARIZED NONSMOOTH FUNCTIONS](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Ertr/papers/rtr158-GeneralizedHessian.pdf), it may be of importance.

UPDATE: 29/01/2020

It seems to me that $c^\star = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j\in[n]} p_j$ may not be a minimizer of $F$, because $G(c)$ may not be zero for any $c\in \mathbb{R}^d$ (there may not be any point which is the "mean" of the points farthest in the sets). This is interesting.